# Code is not Iterating through every name in my CSV file

Tags: python, python-3.x, api, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have an API that I am trying to iterate through, by looking at a CSV file that i have put together, that consists of about 22k MMA Fighter names. What i am trying to do is to get the API to iterate through the CSV file of MMA Fighter names to then gather the data. This works, but it is only capturing between 3-4k of the fighters. I am unsure what about my code is insufficient and would be causing the API to skip so many fighter names?

Is there anything about my code that can be cleaned or maybe something that i can do to prevent this skipping of fighter names from happening?

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import requests, re
from urllib.parse import urljoin
import csv

workbook = open('MMA Fighter NamesUSE.csv', encoding='utf-8')
reader = csv.reader(workbook)
api = 'https://mma.now.sh/?fighter={}'

nameList=[]
nicknameList=[]
fullnameList=[]
recordList=[]
associationList=[]
ageList=[]
birthdayList=[]
hometownList=[]
nationalityList=[]
locationList=[]
heightList =[]
height_cmList=[]
weightList=[]
weight_kgList=[]
weight_classList=[]
collegeList=[]
degreeList=[]
summaryList=[]

for row in reader:
    try:
        r = requests.get(api.format(row))
        data = r.json()

        try:
            name = data['name']
        except AttributeError: name =""
        try:
            nickname = data['nickname']
        except AttributeError: nickname =""
        try:
            fullName = data['fullname']
        except AttributeError: fullname =""
        try:
            record = data['record']
        except AttributeError: record =""
        try:
            association = data['association']
        except AttributeError: association =""
        try:
            age = data['age']
        except AttributeError: age =""
        try:
            birthday = data['birthday']
        except AttributeError: birthday =""
        try:
            hometown = data['hometown']
        except AttributeError: hometown =""
        try:
            nationality = data['nationality']
        except AttributeError: nationality =""
        try:
            location = data['location']
        except AttributeError: location =""
        try:
            height = data['height']
        except AttributeError: height =""
        try:
            height_cm = data['height_cm']
        except AttributeError: height_cm =""
        try:
            weight = data['weight']
        except AttributeError: weight =""
        try:
            weight_kg = data['weight_kg']
        except AttributeError: weight_kg =""
        try:
            weight_class = data['weight_class']
        except AttributeError: weight_class =""
        try:
            college = data['college']
        except AttributeError: college =""
        try:
            degree = data['degree']
        except AttributeError: degree =""
        try:
            summary = data['summary']
        except AttributeError: summary =""


        nameList.append(name)
        nicknameList.append(nickname)
        fullnameList.append(fullName)
        recordList.append(record)
        associationList.append(association)
        ageList.append(age)
        birthdayList.append(birthday)
        hometownList.append(hometown)
        nationalityList.append(nationality)
        locationList.append(location)
        heightList.append(height)
        height_cmList.append(height_cm)
        weightList.append(weight)
        weight_kgList.append(weight_kg)
        weight_classList.append(weight_class)
        collegeList.append(college)
        degreeList.append(degree)
        summaryList.append(summary)

        print(name)

    except ValueError:
        continue

df = pd.DataFrame()
df['name']=nameList
df['nickname']=nicknameList
df['fullname']=fullnameList
df['record']=recordList
df['association']=associationList
df['age']=ageList
df['birthday']=birthdayList
df['hometown']=hometownList
df['nationality']=nationalityList
df['location']=locationList
df['height']=heightList
df['heightCM']=height_cmList
df['weight']=weightList
df['weightKG']=weight_kgList
df['weight_class']=weight_classList
df['college']=collegeList
df['degree']=degreeList
df['summary']=summaryList


df.to_csv('Fighters.csv', index=False)
```

Error message when i remove the **TRY and except ValueError Continue**

```
JSONDecodeError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-99-5509e3e1fc07> in <module>()
     31    # try:
     32         r = requests.get(api.format(row))
---> 33         data = r.json()
     34 
     35         try:

c:\users\administrator\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py in json(self, **kwargs)
    894                     # used.
    895                     pass
--> 896         return complexjson.loads(self.text, **kwargs)
    897 
    898     @property

c:\users\administrator\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\json\__init__.py in loads(s, encoding, cls, object_hook, parse_float, parse_int, parse_constant, object_pairs_hook, **kw)
    352             parse_int is None and parse_float is None and
    353             parse_constant is None and object_pairs_hook is None and not kw):
--> 354         return _default_decoder.decode(s)
    355     if cls is None:
    356         cls = JSONDecoder

c:\users\administrator\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\json\decoder.py in decode(self, s, _w)
    337 
    338         """
--> 339         obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
    340         end = _w(s, end).end()
    341         if end != len(s):

c:\users\administrator\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\json\decoder.py in raw_decode(self, s, idx)
    355             obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
    356         except StopIteration as err:
--> 357             raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
    358         return obj, end

JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

Comment: Just let it fail - temporarily remove/comment out the exception handling and see how it fails. My guess is - it fails with a `ValueError` in some cases which you silently ignore moving forward with `continue`.

Comment: i will try and comment back with error message.

Comment: @alecxe i have added the error message.

Comment: you are probably not getting a json string in the response, inspect the response - it’s likely html with an error message if I were to guess.

Comment: what is the best method to test this or make a change as i am pretty new to this. thank you.

Comment: Put a breakpoint after the `r = requests.get(api.format(row))` line, debug and inspect the value of `r` and `r.text`. It could be there is some sort of the rate-limiting error for the API, for example.

Comment: i have gone through it and its not showing me anything that could be helpful to me. it is not a rate-limiting error though.

Comment: the issue is when the fighter does not exist in the website where the API is making the call it returns that error message. Any idea how i can get around that: so if the fighter does not exist in website to ignore and move to the next?

Comment: This sounds like exactly what you've been doing before asking the question :)